# what is use of ~~ in javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding javascript bitwise NOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133473/understanding-javascript-bitwise-not)

I found it here: [front-end-interview-questions](http://darcyclarke.me/development/front-end-job-interview-questions/) question down below.
what this code ~~3.14 will return?

I searched on google but didn't found anything on this.

Comment: Or [Javascript Tilde & Two's complement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337360/javascript-tilde-twos-complement)

Comment: **Simple answer**: fastest trimming decimals operation (as fast as bitwise OR) `~~3.14` is the same as `3.14 | 0`

Answer (score 5):

`~` is the *bitwise complement* operator in JavaScript (and C/C++ and other languages).
You can find more details here: [How does the bitwise complement (~) operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791328/how-does-the-bitwise-complement-operator-work)

In this case:

- `3.14` is converted from floating point to integer, so it becomes `3`.
- `~3` is `-4` because of the [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation.
- Then `~(-4)` becomes `3`.

Basically, `~n` is equal to `-n-1` for integers with Two's Complement representation.

Answer (score 4):

The tilde performs a [bitwise NOT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#NOT) on the input after converting it to a 32-bit integer.

From the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators):

> Bitwise NOTing any number `x` yields `-(x + 1)`. For example, `~5` yields `-6`.

In your case:

```
  ~~3.14
= -((~3.14) + 1)
= -(-(3.14 + 1) + 1)
= -(-(3 + 1) + 1)
= -(-4 + 1)
= -(-3)
= 3
```

Answer (score 3):

It will return 3. `~` represents bitwise NOT operator in JavaScript.

Basically ~3.14 is same as ~3, which is ~011 in binary => 100 or 4 in base 10.
~4 or ~100 is 011 or 3 in base 10.